# I'm trying to make a second input into a bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a command where you input the command and the bot says: Are you sure? Then you type yes or no but I can't figure out how I can make it so the user can reply. Can someone help please?

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: JavaScript. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have some ways to do that, the easier is to use [`MessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector) to collect the user response.
Example:

```js
message.channel.send("Are you sure?") // Ask the user
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id && (m.content.toLowerCase() === "yes" || m.content.toLowerCase() === "no")  // Create a filter, only accept messages from the user that used the command and the message includes "yes" or "no"
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {time: 30000})
collector.once("collect", msg => {
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
        // User sent yes
    } else {
        // User sent "no"
    }
})
collector.once("stop", (collected, reason) => {
    if(reason === "time") {
        // User took so long to anwser
    }
})
```

You can use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) too, it returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with messages.
Example:

```js
message.channel.send("Are you sure?")

const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id && (m.content.toLowerCase() === "yes" || m.content.toLowerCase() === "no")  // Create a filter, only accept messages from the user that used the command and the message includes "yes" or "no"
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 30000})
    .then(collected => {
        const msg = collected.first()
        if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
            // User sent yes
        } else {
            // User sent "no"
        }
    })
```